# Heroku: RAILS_ROOT returns app folder instead of root folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have this RoR app that calls to RAILS_ROOT.
When running it using rails server (or when checking with `./script/console`) the value contains the app's root.
When deploying and running it with Heroku, however (or when checking with `heroku console`), the returned path is '/app'.

Why's that?

Thanks

Comment: Nothing. I'm using Rails 2.3.5, so Rails.root doesn't exist there.
Unfortunately, I cannot upgrade the environment.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Because on heroku your app is in the `/app` folder (from the root `/`).
It is NOT the app folder of your application, which is `/app/app`.

The file structure is:

```
/app/app/...
/app/config/..
/app/Gemfile
...
```

You can make an experiment.

Run heroku console and discover the file structure.

```
> heroku console
> puts `ls`
> puts `pwd`
```

Comment: Thank you :)

After finding this out (using 'heroku run bash' instead of 'heroku console' though), I managed to find out the problem - a sneaky erroneous file call generated in an extreme case.